# Appengine Developers Console: Where can I see the Zone in which the project was created?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created a project using the [appengine developers console](http://console.developers.google.com). Projects are created either in the US or in the EU zone. However I forgot which one I chose since this was some time ago.
Now i need to have a reliable source of trust in which zone this project was created. I can't find it in the developers console anywhere.

Does anybody know where this little detail can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the zone of your app engine application in the application overview of the [old appengine console](https://appengine.google.com/). There's a column called "Location" which contains the information you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.